# OpenCV imshow() does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, io, computer-vision

I have written an openCV code and my code has following statement:

```
cv::imshow("Matches", matchesImg);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

When I run the code either in Debug or Release I am not able to see window which shows me the output.

And this is happening for every project I create.

Not able to figure out the reason, Can someone please guide me on this?

I am coding on Windows 7 and Visual studio 2010, with opencv version of 2.4.6

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you are confident matchesImg is valid? What error do you get?

Comment: Make sure matchesImg is not empty.

Comment: No the image is not empty. The problem is I don't get any error too. My code runs fine. When I save the image using imwrite I get the proper output. Only the show does not work in any code. I tried reinstalling stuff too.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you have to create a window first, using namedWindow. Use the same name in it as in imshow.

Comment: Had a similar problem, see if this works: `cv::namedWindow("Matches"); cv::imshow("Matches", matchesImg); cv::waitKey();`

Comment: ?? That's what I said, namedWindow !

Comment: @CTZStef Yep you said it first. you should post it as answer! I think the fact that you have to explicitly create a window first with `namedWindow` is a bug in OpenCV.

Comment: @Armin Mustafa,  could you post more code around the two lines you provided so we can understand why `cv::namedWindow("Matches");` apparently fixes the problem? Also, are you using a prebuilt version of OpenCV, or have you rebuilt yourself. Anything else noteworthy, like OpenGL or QT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you have to create a window first, using `namedWindow` with the same window name as in `imshow` 
See this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html) for details.

**EDIT**

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow) strongly suggest that you have to create the window beforehand.
Some may argue that it didn't work this way for previous versions of OpenCV. Then, let's say this solution apply at least to OpenCV 2.4.6, which is the version of concern here  (and it solved the problem).

Comment: While this may be true for 2.4.6, it isn't (for me, at least) on 2.4.4.

Comment: I think it's been true since OpenCV 1.0. Why not for you ?

Comment: I just checked the 2.4.4 source. `imshow()` just calls `cvShowImage()` and, on Windows at least,  if the named window doesn't already exist `cvNamedWindow()` is called to create it. Therefore your answer does not apply to OpenCV 2.4.4 on Windows 7, and possible not other platforms.

Comment: Then the OpenCV documentation is misleading ? Have a look to my edit, and to the link I added. Beside, the functions cvNamedWindow and cvShowImage are C OpenCV, and here we are talking about C++ OpenCV. Therefore I doubt you checked the right source.

Comment: At the link you provided I can't see anything that suggests (even weakly) that the window must be created beforehand. Looking at the C++ source for the function `imshow()` I see that it just calls the C function `cvShowImage()`. You can see that at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.6/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp. Also you can see what `cvShowImage()` does at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.6/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp . Try it for yourself?  Probably there is something else going on the OP's code.  The links are for  OpenCV 2.4.6.

Comment: imshow "Displays an image in the specified window." To me this strongly (not weakly at all) suggests that the window should exists beforehand. Beside, why bother to explicitely call namedWindow() if this is useless (first link example) ? In cvShowImage(), I see window = icvFindWindowByName(name);
    if(!window)
    { ... // Now the question is, if both are possible (create the window beforehand or not) why the former did not work for @ArminMustafa ?

Comment: You need to call `namedWindow()` if you want non-default window propertties.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. `cv::imshow` have always worked without previously creating a `namedWindow`. It may lead to the wrong idea that it is necessary to call `namedWindow` before `imshow`, whereas the problem in the OP's code could be elsewhere.

Comment: Yet, IT SOLVED THE PROBLEM. And I guess you call your comment "accurate"? So tell me, what "have always worked" means? Which version of OpenCV? Anyway, read my comments above. And easy on the downvote before you know what you're talking about.

Comment: @CTZStef First of all, you don't have need to be rude, and no need to DV my other answers just because I disagree. I have read your answer and your comments. What @B... pointed out its true, also for v2.4.6 . Now, here is a more accurate comment: in all recent versions of OpenCV (I have just checked it for versions >=2.3.1), the `cvNamedWindow` method is invoked inside `cvShowImage` (and, therefore, inside `imshow`) when no existing window name is passed. **This is fact** (you can check it in any of those versions, its in src/modules/highgui/src/window_*.cpp (gtk,QT,etc)). Prove it wrong.

Comment: @CTZStef - KeillRandor  is correct. Don't bother with the tutorials, look at the source! `imshow()` calls `cvShowImage()` and, for windows at least, if the window does not exist this code gets executed: `cvNamedWindow(name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`. You ONLY need to call `namedWindow()` first if for some reason `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` doesn't suit you.  OTH, perhaps there IS a bug in `icvFindWindowByName()`. But that doesn't affect me - never used `namedWindow()`

Comment: Who was rude in the first place? You. Instead of downvoting you could have commented first, proposing an edit. Beside, I never DVed anything. Don't be paranoid. Now, I still wonder, why my solution works? There is still no answer to that. Do you have one? Anyway, if you are unhappy with my (accepted) answer, edit it. End of the story as far as I am concerned. cheers.

Comment: @B... I trust you if you checked the code, I cannot do it right now. I would suggest you propose an edit to my answer. HOWEVER I still wonder why my solution worked, I still can't see an explanation to that.

Comment: The possibilities include that icvFindWindowByName() is buggy, and that when the person added namedWindow() to their code they changed something else as well (which I would consider the most likely scenario).

Comment: So, what do we do? If you guys are willing to edit my answer, please go ahead. Or delete it. Or maybe all our comments are enough. Thx.